# Visual Studio Code (VSCode) - how to update the standalone (.zip) version?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There is no "check for updates" when using the standalone/no install version.

What is best way to update a standalone version without losing settings etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [official doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows#_common-questions) it says when downloaded through zip file, one has download the release manually for each update and place the unzip version inside the Program files (Windows).

Answer (score 6):

According to my experience (VSCode in a standalone .zip file uncompressed in D:\ using Win7 OS) you just need to download and uncompress the archive containing the new version (v 1.41.1).

When you run Code.exe in the new folder, your settings file is used and everithing is OK. (then, when you are really really sure that it is everithing OK, you could delete the old version).

If you changed the default settings file location, take a look at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations

Comment: This is the right answer. In newer versions of Code, there's no "data" folder inside the app's own folder anymore.

Comment: You have to create the folder yourself if you use the official download. Otherwise it's not a "portable" installation, just an unzipped non-portable version. See offical [doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable)

Answer (score 3):

According to the special [portable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable) page all the settings, plugins, etc. of the standalone version
are stored in the *data*-folder. So assuming you called your vscode-folder **vscode**:

1. download the new version
2. unpack to vscode2 folder adjacent to current vscode
3. move **data** folder from *vscode* to *vscode2*
4. delete old *vscode*-folder
5. rename *vscode2* to *vscode*
6. done

P.S.: Current portable versions notify about new version, but clicking on it leads to download, so above list still applies.

Edit 2020/08/04: To make a "normal" install portable one just needs to create the **data** folder inside the installation/unpack directory of VSC.

Answer (score 0):

To download the old archive, replace `user|system` with `archive` in the URL.

Before:
`https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.69.2/win32-x64-user/stable`

After:
`https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.69.2/win32-x64-archive/stable`